# Python Invalid Syntax error -> ' <- calles as invalid

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

i have a program im making and im getting the weirdest error all over the place...

I got all of them fixed but now it show's Invalid syntax : '

The statement where it show the error is :

```
hashs <- Int

for i, line in enumerate(fp):

                if i == counter:

                    print(line)

                 if hashs == '1': <- error at the first '
                    line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                    hashc = hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()

                if hashs == '2':
                    line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                    hashc = hashlib.sha1(line).hexdigest()
```

Comment: More context, please. The actual error may be on another line.

Comment: please post the minimal code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You should edit your original answer with your code.  To format your code just highlight it and press ctrl+k.  Also, you should include what `hashs` **is**.

Comment: Yes hashs is declared as integer...  http://pastebin.com/Makib32g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hashs` is an integer like you say, then you should have `if hashs == 1:`, not `'1'`.  `'1'` is a string.

It may have been how you copy and pasted your code, but that `if` statement also looks to be one space to the right more than it should be.  You should decide on a tab convention, 2 spaces, 4 spaces, etc, and use that consistently.

edit:  `counter` and the `while` loop were unnecessary and resulted in an infinite loop.

This code works for me:

```
import hashlib

def main():
    hashs = 0

    read = str(raw_input('Please enter filename for input : '))
    output = str(raw_input('Please enter filename for output : ' ))
    hashs = int(raw_input('Select a Hash to convert to : '))

    if (output != ''):
        fileObj = open(output,"a")

    if (read != ''):
        numlines = 0
        for line in open(read):
            numlines +=1

        print ('Found ', numlines, ' lines to convert\n') 

        fp = open(read)

        for i, line in enumerate(fp):

            if hashs == 1:
                line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()

            if hashs == 2:
                line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.sha1(line).hexdigest()

            if hashs == 3:
                line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.sha224(line).hexdigest()

            if hashs == 4:
                line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.sha256(line).hexdigest()

            if hashs == 5:
                line = line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.sha384(line).hexdigest()

            if hashs == 6:
                line.encode('UTF-8')
                hashc = hashlib.sha512(line).hexdigest()

            fileObj.write(hashc)
            fileObj.write('\n')
main()
```

My input file contains:

```
test file hash this yo
come on and hash, if you want to jam
mankind is to be surpassed
```

Here is my terminal input and output:

```
Please enter filename for input : input
Please enter filename for output : outf 
Select a Hash to convert to : 2
('Found ', 3, ' lines to convert\n')
```

and my outfile then contains:

```
222bc2522767626e27c64bb2b68a787f9e4758cd
f3ac7272e6d681c331580368e4b189445b9a9451
fdca95f9c68df6216af6d2eeb950a3344812bd62
```

**edit** I'm using python 2.7, so you should change your inputs back from `raw_input` to `input`, and your print statement will work correctly.  Python 2.7 just thinks I wanted to print a tuple.

Comment: well i checked all the spaces and tabs and did them again...now it highlights the h at the first if statement...i have updated the pastebin file

Comment: @FierceFuzion: Please copy and paste the current version of your code (*don't* retype) into your question, then highlight it and press Ctrl-k to format it. Putting things like "<- error at the first '" directly into your code only makes it harder for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @user2357112 there is a Pastbin link now with the complete code : http://pastebin.com/fJyArQ8A

Comment: I dont know, thanks for the help but it must be my Laptop ...i tryed to run the code you posted and it is not working...i will try it on my pc... again Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah i just ran it on my pc works like a charm. Thanks for the Hel